# Specifying variables in checkinstall

Tags: compiling

The compile command that I should use is:

```
make  KLIB=/lib/modules/$(uname -r)
```

But as make utility is not good at uninstalling packages I want to use `checkinstall` like so:

```
checkinstall install=no
```

But how can I use `KLIB` variable with `checkintstall`?

Comment: I don't understand. chekinstall substitutes the make install step, not the make (compilation) step in the usual install from source procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Javier pointed out in his comment: checkinstall is only useful for the installation part of the build chain. For some more clarification:

if you ware used to compile and install a program the usual way: ./configure && make && make install you would replace this by:

```
./configure && make && checkinstall install=no
```

so you can still pass the KLIB-Argument to make as this argument is only important for make, not for make install.

Answer (score 1):

The synopsis of `checkinstall` is:

> checkinstall [options]  [install command]

`make install` as the command is just a default. It can run any installation command in a supervised way.

To pass another command or `make install` with additional arguments such as variables, use the `[install command]` argument, as in:

```
sudo checkinstall make install KLIB=/lib/modules/$(uname -r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
./configure --KLIB=/lib/modules/$(uname -r) --install=no
make
checkinstall
```

You can provide an argument to `./configure` and then run `make` and `checkinstall`.

https://michaelrigart.be/creating-debian-packages-checkinstall/